# Sequelize.js - findAll with Ordering

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am doing a findAll after joining two tables. The query looks something like this:

```
user.findAll({
    order: ['username', 'DESC'],
    include: [{
        model: profile_table,
        where: {
            favouriteColor: 'red'
        }
    }]
```

Here is an example of the array-object that the query is searching through:

```
[{
    'id': '8i394324sd',
    'username': 'Joey',
    'profile': [{
        'favouriteColor': 'red',
        'admin': 'false'
     }]
}]
```

Here is my problem: what if I want to set the `order` field so that it orders the list by `admin`. How do I go about doing this? I can't exactly do:

```
order: [`${profile.admin}`, 'DESC']
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
order: [[${profile_table.name}.admin, 'DESC']]
```

option.